# Qt creator не видит некоторые функции QTextStream

Tags: c++, qt

Начал изучать Qt и в одном из уроков есть такой код:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDate>
#include <QTime>
 
int main() {
    
   QTextStream out(stdout);
   out.setCodec("CP866"); // устанавливаем CP866-кодировку для консоли 

   return 0;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что у меня нет функции `setCodec()`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Точно так же не было найдено `QStringRef`

Может эти уроки устарели и появились какие то альтернативные функции?

Использую

QT Creator 4.15.1

Qt 6.1.1 MinGW 64-bit

Windows 10

Comment: да вроде нет https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec

Comment: @KoVadim вот и я смотрел документацию, все вроде бы есть

Comment: Эти методы убраны в Qt6. Заменой `QStringRef` является `QStringView`, на счет `setCodec` не помню точно. Вы смотрите документацию на Qt5

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Спасибо и на этом, хоть понял в чем причина